# Nested form not rendering (Phoenix Framework)

Tags: phoenix-framework

I have a very simple form. A `User` can register and also specify the name of their `Organisation`. For some reason, the nested form (via `inputs_for`) which captures the Organisation name is not appearing on the page. Any ideas?

```
<%= form_for @changeset, Routes.user_registration_path(@conn, :create), fn f -> %>
...

  <%= label f, :first_name%>
  <%= text_input f, :first_name, required: true %>
  <%= error_tag f, :first_name %>

...

  <%= inputs_for f, :organisations, fn o -> %>
    <%= label o, :name%>
    <%= text_input o, :name %>
  <% end %>

...

  <div>
    <%= submit "Register" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple form, simple problem, simple answer.

The `organisations` list was empty. I needed to populate it with an empty list with an empty `organisation` struct before rendering the form.

Example:

```
user = %User{user | organisations: [%Organisation{}]}
```

Comment: Looks to be a changeset issue.  The idea is that the changeset needs to know which associations it will be tracking.  In the future if you need to handle more than one organization on the form, you'll need to populate the changeset with a dynamic list of changesets.